# Connect to a Cisco switch with SSH and Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, switch-statement

I'm trying to connect to a Cisco Switch with SSH and ruby. The problem is that I need to enter an empty 'login as' then it will ask me for an User Name and Password. On Putty I do like this:
[image: Putty]

Here is how i have tried to connect with NET::SSH.

```
CISCO = "host" #Enter the IP address here 
USER = "operacao" #Enter username here 
PASS = "" #Enter password here 
tn = Net::SSH::Telnet::new("Host" => CISCO, "Timeout" => 60, "Prompt" => /^\login as:/ ) 
tn.cmd("\n") { |c| print c } 
tn.cmd("\n#{USER}") { |c| print c } 
tn.cmd(PASS) { |c| print c } 
tn.print("echo oi") { |c| print c } 
tn.close
```

Is there any way to do this with Ruby?

Comment: Please post your code and the error messages. How could anyone help you if you don't show what're you doing?

Comment: @amalrik maia my last try was:
CISCO = "host" #Enter the IP address here
USER = "operacao" #Enter username here
PASS = "" #Enter password here

tn = Net::SSH::Telnet::new("Host" => CISCO,
"Timeout" => 60,
"Prompt" => /^\login as:/ )

tn.cmd("\n") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd("\n#{USER}") { |c| print c }
tn.cmd(PASS) { |c| print c }
tn.print("echo oi") { |c| print c }
tn.close

Comment: @amalrikmaia: Next time, please mention in your edit comment where the code is coming from. Makes it easier for reviewers to see that it's a valid edit.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I see "login as:" then "User Name:" and "Password". Since I'm not familiar with Cisco switches and when I watched the following video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=3v3Iw87vEQ8#t=566s) the username and password were provided for the SSH layer, IOS one.

Depending on whether you can ask for all the credentials directly from SSH or if you must in part go through IOS, I should be able to provide a tailored solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find this sample [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/networking/qt/netssh.htm) i hope this gives you some direction.
Before you run this code certify that you run: 
 `gem install net-ssh`

```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby
   require 'net/ssh'

   HOST = '192.168.1.113'
   USER = 'username'
   PASS = 'password'

   Net::SSH.start( HOST, USER, :password => PASS ) do|ssh|
   result = ssh.exec!('ls')
   puts result
   end
```

The only requirement of Net::SSH are openSSL bindings for ruby, you can check if you ok  with this:

```
C:\Sites>ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.0k 5 Feb 2013

C:\Sites>
```

EDIT: 
I did some research and found some answers, i think you should take a look at:
[telnet to a cisco switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649933/ruby-script-to-telnet-switch) and 
[net-ssh to configure a juniper router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327141/using-ruby-gem-net-ssh-to-configure-a-juniper-router)